# How do I switch to google plus page on android app?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-plus

Using code in android Intent, I am able to switch From APP to  google plus page using the internet via http://plus.google.com

however, I am unable to switch on the Android app back from Google Plus browser.

Please advise on how to switch on the Android app back from Google Plus browser?

UPDATE:

I have now moved the question to webapps.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29438/how-to-switch-google-plus-managing-as-page-in-the-g-android-app

Comment: Is this a programming question? If so, it's unclear and seems to lack research effort. If not, then perhaps you should consider posting on an Android forum. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: This question is too vague / clear to be answerable without *guessing* what you really mean.  Please clarify the question ... or it is likely to continue to attract down-votes, and eventual closure.

Comment: Ok i apologise. this is not a programming question per se. I moved the question to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29438/how-to-switch-google-plus-managing-as-page-in-the-g-android-app How do I close this question myself?

Comment: even then I am not entirely sure this is the right SE site to move to. If I am not right, please tell me. Down-voting me at webapps without telling me where won't help.

Answer (score 0):

**Override an following method into your activity**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent ip = new Intent(this, youactivity.class);
    startActivity(ip);
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```